# ZWJ in LuaTeX prints a bar

Tags: luatex, unicode, arabic

The following document prints in XeTeX the medial form of the arabic letter, thanks to the two ZWJ characters ("200D).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arabic Typesetting}

\begin{document}
\char"200Dي\char"200D
\end{document}
```

However, in LuaTeX I get:

[image: ZWJ glyphs]

The two glyphs for the ZWJ are actually in the font, but they shouldn't be shown. How can I hide them?

**EDIT.** For this particular case, the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arabic Typesetting}

\begin{luacode*}
s = 'EU2/ArabicTypesetting(0)/m/n/10' 
local i = font.id(s)
local f = font.getfont(i)
f.characters[8205].index = 3
font.setfont(i, f)
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\char"200Dي\char"200D

ي\char"200D

\char"200Dي

ي  

\end{document}
```

However, I'm still wondering if there is a more elegant and general approach based on a simple switch.

Comment: Are you sure that `ZWNJ` corresponds to slot `x200D`? In some of my own past work, I've used `x200C` for this invisible character. The slot `x200D` should be occupied by the `ZWJ` (zero width joiner) glyph.

Comment: I meant ZWJ, indeed. I edited the question.

Comment: Why not `\char"FEF4` ?

Comment: @salimbou Some fonts convert the presentation forms to the isolated ones. Anyway, the problem here is not getting the medial form, but the glyph shown by the ZWJ.

Comment: @JavierBezos Since `fontspec` for LuaTeX uses `luaotfload`, that ultimately uses the ConTeXt shaping engine, that depends on what ConTeXt does, so you'll have to convince Hans to use ZWJ correctly.

Comment: Just give up trying to use LuaTeX. Font shaping is a complex problem, and the best solution in the open-source world is Harfbuzz, worked on full-time by engineers at Google and Mozilla. It is what XeTeX uses. LuaTeX has the dream of doing font shaping within the engine itself (in Lua code), which is rather too ambitious. I doubt if it will ever be achieved. And unsurprisingly, LuaTeX doesn't support any more than a few scripts (e.g. the only Indic script it supports is Devanagari, and that too very buggily), while XeTeX uses your system libraries and supports any script your system does.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I know XeTeX.

Comment: @Sebastiano How is this solved in the comments?

Comment: @Sebastiano But the point was that XeTeX uses Harfbuzz, but LuaTeX uses luaotfload and the question asks how to hide the ZWJ with LuaTeX.

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed in TeX Live 2021, but to anyone else who has this problem, I would suggest trying `^^^^200d`, not `\char"200D`. The former is the Unicode character itself, and the latter literally means to display the glyph in that slot of the font.

Comment: I don’t have an installation that reproduces the bug, so I don’t know whether that would actually help.

Answer (score 2):

LuaTeX has HarfBuzz now. Rendering is OK.

[image: zwj example]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arabic Typesetting}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\char"200Dي\char"200D & \textdir TRT  ي ييي \\
\char"200Dب\char"200D & \textdir TRT  ب ببب\\
\char"200Dش\char"200D & \textdir TRT ش ششش\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, your example is using the default renderer, not Harfbuzz . With Harfbuzz it fails!  I didn’t remember this question. Thank you for updating it, and it may be convenient to close it, because things have changed a lot in the past five years.

Comment: @JavierBezos I don't get any issues when trying this with HarfBuzz, but I don't have the font used here. Could you write a bug report for that and/or send me a MNWE (preferably with open fonts if possible)?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger On TeX Live 2021 for Windows, it succeeds with either `Renderer=Node` or `Renderer=HarfBuzz`.